# Exact match with special characters in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I using solr 4.6.1, I have one problem in searching string with special charcters, let me tell you one example

if I search string `"choose:"` then results having string `<choose>` comes first and then results with exact match `<choose:>` comes at the end of result set.

Please tell me what I have to do to solve this problem.

```
"params": {
      "lowercaseOperators": "true",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "type:service AND tags:\"choose:\"",
      "qf": "tags^8",
      "_": "1406201797319",
      "stopwords": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "defType": "edismax"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search against a StrField, only exact matches will count. You can then score these matches higher, using `qf=exact^8 text` (if using `dismax` or `edismax` as your query parser). In standard Lucene syntax you can search for `exact:"choose:"^8 OR text:"choose:"` to score the exact matches higher.

Comment: @Anubhav As mentioned, you'll have to search against a StrField to get exact matches only (or possibly a textfield with a KeywordTokenizer). What is the definition of the tags field?

Comment: @Anubhav Which will, by default, strip off special characters, break the text into words, etc. Add an alternative field as a StrField, use a `<copyField>` directive to add content to both fields, then boost the field with the exact match more than the one with a non-exact match.